# Importing external jar in Talend

Tags: java, talend

Can anyone please help me with this issue. I have installed the Talend studio (Talend Data Fabric 7.3.1) successfully. But when i tried connecting to Azure SQL database using tDBInput component , it showed me an error that jar "mssql-jdbc.jar" is missing. Since the download button is disabled.

Please see the below snapshot showing that download button is disabled

[image: screenshot showing download buttion in component is disabled]

I manually downloaded the jar "mssql-jdbc-8.4.0.jre11" and pointed it to the component. When i executed my Talend job it showed following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
      at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
      at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
      at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
      at psc_co_biopharm.test_job_0_1.Test_job.tDBInput_2Process(Test_job.java:727)
      at psc_co_biopharm.test_job_0_1.Test_job.runJobInTOS(Test_job.java:1458)
      at psc_co_biopharm.test_job_0_1.Test_job.main(Test_job.java:1240)
```

So, i tried a work around . Used tlibraryload component to import the jar "mssql-jdbc-8.2.1jre11". It worked and i was able to query the Azure SQL database.

[image: Screenshot showing that tlibraryload worked fine]

But using tlibraryload is not the best practise, could someone please tell me how to point this version of jar "mssql-jdbc-8.2.1jre11" directly to component.

I tried loading this jre via windows->show_view->Modules. But it showing that "This module is already installed with the maven URI"

[image: Screenshot showing that import of jre via windows->showview->modules didn't work]

Kindly help me and advise how to  point this version of jar "mssql-jdbc-8.2.1jre11" directly to component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posting the answer for this issue,so this would help someone in future. The mistake i have done is , At the first place itself i should have downloaded the "mssql-jdbc-8.2.1jre11" jar and pointed it to the component, instead i have downloaded "mssql-jdbc-9.1jre" and pointed to the component. That's a terrible mistake.

Make sure you are downloading the proper version of jar which is compatible with your jdk. For me the jdk version is 11 so i should have downloaded "mssql-jdbc-8.2.1jre11" jar at first place itself.

Since i already downloaded different version of jar and pointed to the component at first place, it's not accepting the correct version of jar "mssql-jdbc-8.2.1jre11" which i am pointing now. We should delete the old jar from the following folder and the we should try to import the correct version of jar. it will work. It worked very well for me.

We should delete the old jar from the following folder in our system

Windows(c)->Talend_Studio->Configuration->.m2->repository->org->Talend->Libraries

Under this libraries folder, for my case i should find the folder MySQL directory and delete it.

Then i tried importing the jar via   windows->show_view->Modules it worked. :-)

Hope this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Be Make sure,

1. The java JDK requirements and version compatibility with Talend Studio and check the version java -version in cmd
2. Since its Maven repository the required supporting library(Archive Jar) are downloaded when workspace is build and clean the project
3. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver exception version mismatch of mssql-jdbc.jar
4. Check maven repo installed : Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings > Local Repository and if maven is installed in your system \Maven\apache-maven-3.0.3\conf\setting.xml Dir Path all the library download here
5. Delete / Remove the jar from .m2->repository->org->Talend->Libraries -> mssql-jdbc(6.0.0)
6. Clean the workspace ensure old version of archive file is removed
7. Build the workspace provided maven URI is configured in the system it will auto-download the current version supporting lib or
8. Manual import the archive file windows->show_view->Modules
9. Restart the studio

Hope this is useful . !